# ui-router : no binding, no loadings no errors

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

EDIT : Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6meeuAOQKKaPaMYFYXKk?p=preview)

I'm a bit disappointed about the issue I have with `ui-router` as it is a very basic use.

I have an "empty" html index file that welcomes `ui-views`. I created 2 main templates : `application.html` and `public.html` . Basically they have 2 different headers/footers.

*index.html*

```
 <div ui-view="">    
  <!-- encapsulate app/public -->
  <a ui-sref="app">app</a>
 </div>
```

*app-routes.js*

```
 var myApp = angular.module('taApp',      ['ui.router','ui.bootstrap','ui.sortable', 'ngResource']);
   myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
   //

   // For any unmatched url, redirect to /auth
   $urlRouterProvider.when("", "/auth");
   $urlRouterProvider.when("/", "/auth");
   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/auth");

   $stateProvider
   .state('public', {
    url:'',
    abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'public.html',
        /*views: {
        'topbar': { template: 'public.topbar' },
        'login': { template: 'public.login' }
        }*/
     })
     .state('auth', {
         url: '/auth',
         templateUrl: '/partials/login/loginCard.html'
     })

     /*** LOGGED STATES ***/
     //login
     .state('app', {
         templateUrl: 'application.html',
         controller: 'authCtrl',
       url: '/app'
     })
  });
```

Notice: the `ui-sref` state doesn't work too as it should load 'app' state.
Also I tried to force `ui-view="app"` or `"public"` without any success

I use `angular-ui-router` package on `gulp`.

There is something I missed and can't figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the updated question, related [to this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6meeuAOQKKaPaMYFYXKk?p=preview), I updated that and [make it working](http://plnkr.co/edit/NSLOvI39fv0ht9YsvJ1Z?p=preview).

Fistly, angular must be loaded first

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
```

we need this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

And also, because our application `"taApp"` is defined:

```
var myApp = angular.module('taApp', 
[
    'ui.router' //,'ui.bootstrap','ui.sortable', 'ngResource'
]);
```

we have add that into index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="taApp">
```

And as we can see, because we are not having references to other module (inside of index.thml) I had to comment them out

```
 'ui.router' //,'ui.bootstrap','ui.sortable', 'ngResource'
```

But once their code will be added to the page... it will work with them. So, this example is [no working here](http://plnkr.co/edit/NSLOvI39fv0ht9YsvJ1Z?p=preview)

Comment: yeah I forgot it in the plunker file sorry ! DId you change something else ? As I changed my plunkr to add the 2 missings you mentioned .. and it still doesn't bind

Comment: nvm ! the error seems related to another angular library. I didn't see you commented other dependancies. I have to check them deeper. Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1):

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/H1hPMiuC89HzAcJNPrrl?p=preview)

I guess that the `public` state, marked as abstract should be parent of all states. So we need to adjust state def like this:

```
  $stateProvider
    .state('public', {
      url: '',
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: 'public.html',
      /*views: {
    'topbar': { template: 'public.topbar' },
    'login': { template: 'public.login' }
    }*/
    })
    .state('auth', {
      parent: 'public',
      url: '/auth',
      templateUrl: 'partials/login/loginCard.html'
    })

  /*** LOGGED STATES ***/
  //login
  .state('app', {
    parent: 'public',
    templateUrl: 'application.html',
    controller: 'authCtrl',
    url: '/app'
  })
```

Any child state is inserting its view into parent - by default. So we must be sure, that the parent template **`public.html`** contains

```
<div ui-view=""></div>
```

There are other ways, but this is the most simple scenario

Comment: nope public and app are on same level. But in close future, each of them will have 2 children : header and footer ( as the typical tutorial viewA and viewB ). It only redirects to public/auth by default

Comment: Well, then it is even more easier, just remove the `parent: 'public'` and all will work. Observe my plunker and you should see what is different... Oh, you provided plunker.. will try to observe it

Comment: I added a plunker on topic with real content templates. I have the same issue

Comment: Had to add new answer with all the details related to your version of a plunker. Hope it is clear now.. the auth is not child of public anymore.. but could be as shown here. Good luck with UI-Router